# Set an info panel or a div over a google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://prntscr.com/7r1s0m

Anyone knows how to do that?

I am trying to set this but i cant... this is my code:

```
        <script>    

          function init_map() {
            var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(46.206958, 6.145097);

            var var_mapoptions = {
              center: var_location,
              zoom: 16
            };



            var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: var_location,
                map: var_map,
                title:"Venice"});

            var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
                var_mapoptions);


            var_marker.setMap(var_map); 

          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map); 
        </script>
```

I try do anything i see in google but i dont found a solution, anyone have the same problem? is it possible to do?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the undesirable behavior you are seeing, rather than just saying "I can't" or "it doesn't work". Try to be more specific about the exact problem you are having.

Comment: thanks, i am improving my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative positioning. Assuming an HTML layout of:

```
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas">Google Map Here</div>
  <div id="panel">Text<br>Text<br>Text</div>
</body>
```

The CSS would be like:

```
#map-canvas {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin-20px;
}
#panel {
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}
```

What this does is set some sizes of the `map-canvas`, and then make the panel positioned somewhere in its parent element. The measurements from the top and left side of the parent element, `body`, are given as `top` and `left`.

For further questions, please Google something like `CSS relative positioning`, and see what is helpful there.

Comment: Just 20 min ago i use this code and it worked! thx for the answer